# How to redirect a url like https://mydomain.com to https://www.mydomain.com from within Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

I am using a SSL cert for www.mydomain.com from GoDaddy on Heroku. How can I redirect from the root url, https: //mydomain.com to https: //www.mydomain.com from within rails so my cert will work? I have been able to redirect all other combination with custom middleware, so that SSL is always serverd, but can't figure out how to do this without the browser detecting the lack of a cert for https://mydomain.com/. Is there something like a rack env[HOST] that I can rewrite?   Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 4):

The browser compares the cert to the domain name way before Rails even gets a chance to touch it - in fact, it's the very first part of the negotiation with the server, so you can't even use Apache Rewrite to change it.

What you should do is add mydomain.com to your cert. They're called "unified communications" certificate, although GoDaddy just calls them a Multiple Domain cert. http://help.godaddy.com/article/3908

Comment: I've had the same problem before and that is the only real solution. The other "solution" is the avoid using the domain you don't have certificate. Redicting users from http://domain to http://www. helps eliminiting most of people accessing the domain you dont have certificate.